# Won't Query on the UPDATE part of the program

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time identifying the cause of the problem of my code, which is, it won't query on the "UPDATE" part but the "SELECT" part does work. when i tried using the print_r function, it gives an errors/warnings namely:

> "Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli"** and **"Warning:
>   mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given"

```
if(!isset($_POST['n_pass'])&&!isset($_POST['n_pass'])){

    if(!isset($_POST['password'])||$_POST['password']==""){
            echo 'enter current password';
            die;
    } else {
            include 'include/database.php';
            $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
            $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lname']);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uname']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

            //Check if the password is equal to the password inside database
            $sql = "SELECT password FROM users where id = $id";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $cpass = $row['password'];
            $verify_pass = password_verify($password,$cpass); //check if current password is equal to the existing password

            if($verify_pass != 1){
                echo 'incorrect password';
                die;
            } else {
                **//Update Data
                $sql="UPDATE users SET firstname=$fname, lastname=$lname, email=$email, username=$username where id=$id";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                print_r($row['firstname']);
                die;
                header("Location: profile.php?successfullyupdated");
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: where u define this `$id`, use `mysqli_num_rows` before fetching. and why are u using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `UPDATE`

Comment: Get rid of the escaping and parameterize. It will fix your update as well. Also if you didn't store the password escaped it won't match.

Comment: You're not checking if your query has been successful and this is the consequence. **Always** check what `mysqli_query` is returning before trying to process it.

Comment: its contains the session variable that i have.

Comment: Additionally it is unclear what you expect `print_r($row['firstname']);` to do, an `update` won't return a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing the quotes around the strings:

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='$fname', lastname='$lname', email='$email', username='$username' where id=$id";
```

You can skip only the id field since it is an Integer.

Sidenote: **you are wide open to SQL Injections. You should use prepared statements.**
There are plenty of resources on google to start with this topic

Finally, note that

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
print_r($row['firstname']);
```

is completely useless since you are not returning anything from the UPDATE query.
You can do:

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    //query was successful - run your code here for success
}else{
    //query failed - run your code here for fail
}
```

Comment: one more thing, OP using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `UPDATE`, this method is only for getting rows, please add in your answer

Comment: Thank You very much, you're right, the missing (') is the cause of my problem... It works already. Thank you everyone for your help. :)

Comment: fix also the second part of your code please. And consider marking the answer if this fixed your issue